# Como chamar uma function em JavaScript dentro de um Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou programando em ASP.NET MVC e tenho um formulário de cadastro. Preciso verificar se a data de nascimento é válida, ou seja, se é menor que a data de hoje. Eu tenho o script mas não sei chamá-lo dentro da `form` abaixo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<div class="form-group">    
  <label><span class="req"></span> Data de Nascimento</label>    
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })    
</div>
```

Peguei esse script de uma outra resposta para implementar:

```
function verificaData() 
{
    var dt = new Date();
    var dia = dt.getDay();
    var mes = dt.getMonth();
    var ano = dt.getFullYear();

    if(dia > 0 && dia < 10) dia = "0" + dia;
    if(mes > 0 && mes < 10) mes = "0" + mes;

    var dataAtual = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    var vDia = document.model.DataNascimento.value.substr(0,2);
    var vMes = document.model.DataNascimento.value.substr(3, 2);
    var vAno = document.model.DataNascimento.value.substr(6, 5);

    if(vDia > dia ||
       vMes > mes ||
       vAno > ano) 
    {
        alert("Data Inválida");
        document.model.DataNascimento.value = dataAtual;
        document.model.DataNascimento.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é simples...basta mudar o botão de submit para um link (elemento a) e com uma função que pegue o clique, captura a data informada, chama a tua função é depois da um submit manual...amanhã vou estar bem enrolado...não sei se consigo lhe manda um exemplo mas depois de amanhã me cobre que mando

Answer (score 0):

O seu form será enviado ao Controller quando o usuário der submit.

Lá, você pode chamar sua função para validar a data e, caso esteja errado, retornar ao form com mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ao atributo onchange do seu elemento a função `verificaData()`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "verificaData()" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

O melhor evento para verificar a data é a saída do campo, feita pelo evento [`onblur`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onblur = "verificaData()" } })
```